# How to reinstall and activate Adobe InDesign CS2 (Polish)?

Tags: installation, locale, adobe-indesign, software-activation, adobe-creative-suite

I have a client that needs to reinstall their computer. They have a Polish version of InDesign CS2, which won’t activate anymore. How to install it after reinstalling Windows? The English version from Adobe’s website is not an acceptable substitute.

Comment: So, am I correct assuming they have no original installation disc anymore? If the English version is available on the website, they should have a Polish one as well. AFAIK, multilingual installers are available for any Adobe product. If the real problem is that it doesn't activate anymore, have you considered contacting Adobe support?

Comment: @slhck They have the original disc, problem is it won’t activate.

Comment: Also, the telephone number Adobe posted on [their site](http://www.adobe.com/pl/support/contact/index.html) not only does not exist, but also is obviously incorrect (Polish tel numbers have 9 digits, not 10).

Comment: @slhck You said they have the Polish version. Where did you find it?

Comment: I didn't say I found one, but as far as I remembered, many major Adobe  products always came as multilingual downloads as well. But if they have the original CD, that should't really be the issue – you'd still be able to install it, right? The activation is the real problem.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this: Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to trick the Polish version into accepting the volume licence serial given on Adobe’s website. Here’s how you do it:

1. Install the Polish version normally. Do not run it.
2. Replace the files `epic_pers.dll`, `Required\idsn.sif` and `Required\Basic Tools.rpln` with ones from the English volume version from Adobe’s website
3. Run InDesign as admin and enter the key from Adobe’s website
4. Install all available updates:

   - [Updater 4.0.5](https://download.adobe.com/pub/adobe/aum/win/AdobeUpdater405.exe)
   - [InDesign CE 4.0.5](http://download.winsoft-international.com/Public/Updates/FromRDV/Private/Updates/IDCE4_05updaterWin.zip)

     - Winsoft seems to be permanently offline and/or bankrupt, so here is a [mirror](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlaD0_9bis3ShMQRa87RT2t0kUAHZA)
   - [Bridge 1.0.3](https://download.adobe.com/pub/adobe/bridge/win/1.x/Adobe_Bridge_1.0.3.zip)
   - [Bridge 1.0.4](https://download.adobe.com/pub/adobe/bridge/win/1.x/AdobeBridge_1.0.4_updater.exe) (requires 1.0.3)
   - <s>[RAID compatibility update](http://www.adobe.com/support/creativesuite/ts/documents/kb409127/270_patch.zip)</s> (not needed, because we bypass activation)
   - [Help Center 2.1](https://download.adobe.com/pub/adobe/helpcenter/Win/Adobe_Help_Center_2.1.exe)
   - [Stock Photos suppressor](https://download.adobe.com/pub/adobe/stockphotos/win/1.x/Adobe%20Stock%20Photos%201.0.9.exe)
   - [ExtendScript 1.0.3](https://download.adobe.com/pub/adobe/extendscript_toolkit/win/Adobe_ExtendScript_Toolkit_1_0.msi) (msi file)
   - [Camera Raw 3.7](https://download.adobe.com/pub/adobe/photoshop/cameraraw/win/3.x/Camera_Raw_3_7.zip)

EDIT: Delete the registry entry `AUMAppID` in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{7F4C8163-F259-49A0-A018-2857A90578BC}` to get rid of the annoying error on startup.

I suppose this procedure could be adapted for other products.

If you ever need to uninstall InDesign, you may need to replace the `Required\idsn.sif` file with the original one and re-enter the original serial, otherwise the uninstall will fail!

Comment: That's impressive. Have you found it out by trial and error or some other way? (I'm not sure if EULA allows this, though)

Comment: @gronostaj I used Sysinternals Process Monitor to find out. The EULA is null and void anyway AFAIK in this case since it is binding for both sides (at least on this side of the Atlantic)

Comment: @kinokijuf What specific entries should I look for in Process Monitor? I'm trying to install whole CS2 in Polish. The trick you've given works for InDesign, but not the rest (Acrobat, Illustrator, ImageReady, Photoshop and GoLive).

Comment: @kinokijuf bump

Answer (score -2):

Adobe has disabled the online activation servers for their old products. You need to download the new Adobe InDesign CS2 installation package (which does not require online activation) from adobe.com

Comment: -1 I explicitely mentioned that the English version is not an acceptable substitute.

Comment: you can ask for whatever you want. it does not mean that you are going to get it. your options are 1) install English CS2 2) buy Polish CS6 3) go without

Comment: I mentioned that it is not me having this problem. I would be fine with an English version myself.

Comment: Also, do you _know_ how much InDesign CS6 costs?